# CSS declarations are displayed twice in Chrome Inspector Tool?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, overriding

I don't know what bug it is, but it hurts. 
Just look at the picture and tell me what do you think it is and how to fix?
[As you can see problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdIAu.png), all classes duplicate itself.

Comment: can provide us the link for more inspection?

Comment: Maybe the div class container has two classes container...<div class="container container"></div>

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Because even `body *` and `*` global styles are repeated.

Comment: You probably linked the `style.css` twice. Check your  `html head`

Comment: You was right! My bundle.js (from Webpack) do this link to .css file second time. Thank you all.

Answer (score 7):

Probably styles.css is linked 2 times in your HTML. Check the content of head tag.